# PDF Raw data - what is this? And how can I use it to display in an iframe or PDF.js viewer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, axios, pdf.js

Hello Stack Overflow.

I need help, I am trying to store PDFs offline on a PWA. But first I simply want to retrieve the PDF from the Wordpress REST API and display it in a iframe or even better Pdf.js.

I have successfully managed to GET the a PDF from the API. When testing in postman it displays the PDF that I can scroll through. However, when using the same GET request in a async axios request I get the following.

```
// Request
async getPDFTest() {
    if (typeof indexedDB === 'undefined') {
      this.supported = false;
    }

    await axios.get('https://staging-nasapi.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Transitions-PG_E.pdf')
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        const pdf1 = response;
        console.log(pdf1);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // handle error
        console.log('Error getting offline PDF');
      });

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve();
    });
  },
};
```

See console log message below.
[Image of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZqG5.png)

How can I get this PDF data into an Iframe or Pdf.js?

Thanks

Comment: You can see the correct data in `response.data`.